# SQL Server : SQL Notifications - it seems ok but

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, notifications, sql-server-2014

a little question. How can I do sql query notification work?

I'm using SQL 2014 and I have followed some tutorial, especially [this](https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2015/04/17/sql-service-query-notifications-and-their-management-from-a-c-application/).

Further, I use C# like in the tutorial, so it is all the same...

It seems all ok, but I never get notified... why? I'm missing some parameters or something-else?

It doesn't happen nothing when the notify event should be fired.. can you help me?

**UPDATE**:

my code:

```
public delegate void delegateUpd();

private void elapse(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    t.Stop();
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new delegateUpd(doUpdate));
    //MainWindowViewModel.stillBusy = false;
}

private static SqlWatcher SqlQueueWatcher;

private static bool isStartTime = true;

public void SQLServiceStart()
{
    if (isStartTime)
    {
        t = new System.Timers.Timer();
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Elapsed += elapse;
    }
    string connS = TmsAdvanceModel.Entities.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;// +"Password=" + attivazione.mdlImpostazioni.p.dbPassword + ";";
    if (!connS.Contains("Password"))
        connS += "Password=" + attivazione.mdlImpostazioni.p.dbPassword + ";";
    //Build the command object we want to monitor (don't include a SqlConnection)
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM dbo.TabNotifiche");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    //Setup the SQLWatcher
    SqlQueueWatcher = new SqlWatcher(connS, cmd, SqlWatcherNotificationType.Blocking);
    SqlQueueWatcher.OnChange += new SqlWatcher.SqlWatcherEventHandler(QueueSQLWatcher_OnChange);
    SqlQueueWatcher.Start();
}

int counter = 0;
private void QueueSQLWatcher_OnChange(DataSet Result)
{
    try
    {
        R = Result;
        //Do something with the updated DataSet object
        if (!isStartTime)
        {
            if (t.Enabled)
            {
                t.Stop();
                t.Start();
            }
            else
                t.Start();
        }
        else
            isStartTime = false;
        counter++;
        Debug.WriteLine("Counter: " + counter.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

public static void SQLServiceStop()
{
    SqlQueueWatcher.Dispose();
}
```

**Are there any particular cases where it notifications doesn't work?**

Comment: We don't see code so we do not know what are you missing or why it is not working

Comment: my code is the same of the tutorial, but ok.. some minutes and I'll post it

Comment: Looked in the server logs?

Comment: @AlexK. no... can you tell me where I can find the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you enabling the broker like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172133(v=vs.110).aspx)?

ALTER DATABASE databsename SET ENABLE_BROKER;

Can you tell the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, I've done it...are there any particular cases where it notifications doesn't work?

Comment: Are you editing the ID column? You need to edit the column you have specified in the SELECT clause.